# Spring - Mybatis reload fragment from XML

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a WebApp using `JRebel (7)` and `Spring-Mybatis (1.3.1)`

When I change an `sql` `statement` inside an `XML mapper` file while the `AppServer (Tomcat 8)` is running, the updated `SQL` **does** get executed by the framework.

```
<select ... >
```

If I change an `sql` `fragment` in an `XML` file, the changes **don't** get reflected in the query executed, until I restart the Application server.

```
<sql ... >
```

Is there a way to reload the `Sql` `fragment` from file, either via configuration or `Java` call?

Comment: Support for reloading <sql> fragments was added in Jrebel 7.1.0: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/changelog/7-x/#agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way...

In my AppConfig, I scope the bean that provides an SqlSessionFactory with `prototype` scope - then it re-creates the bean on every request, and caching is broken.  This is of course highly inefficient; but it's a nifty work-around on the Developer PC while you're working on an SQL fragment:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HotswapAgent has a new MyBatis plugin now https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent , it could handle MyBatis configuration reload.